# Thurston's "tinker toy" problem

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

In the article "On Being Thurstonized" by Benson Farb (located [here)](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~farb/papers/thurston.pdf), a particular result of Thurston is mentioned.

Namely, suppose a "tinker toy" $T$ is a contraption consisting of a multitude of rods. They can either be bolted to a table, or attached to each other along hinges. The configuration space $C(T)$ consists of all possible configurations of $T$. For example, if $T$ is a single segment, then $C(T)$ is a circle.

The claim is then that *any* compact, smooth manifold can be obtained as a component of some $C(T)$.

I've thought about it a bit (though perhaps not enough), and this theorem escapes me completely. Are there any notes or explanations out there that describe the proof of this theorem?

Comment: I am not sure about this problem. I heard that for any manifold M (probably one needs compact and smooth) and any positive real epsilon, there was a T (called a linkage) such that C(T) was epsilon close to M, either by embedding both in R^n or by assigning some metric and finding a near isometry. But this is not my field, and I am recalling something from another millennium.  Gerhard "Gee, I Feel Really Creaky" Paseman, 2018.03.21.

Comment: See:  **Geometric Folding Algorithms:  Linkages, Origami, Polyhedra** by Erik Domaine and Joseph O'Rourke https://www.amazon.com/Geometric-Folding-Algorithms-Linkages-Polyhedra/dp/0521715229/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1521667904&sr=8-3&keywords=Joseph+O%27Rourke

Comment: Take a look here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9807023.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the link to Benson's essay! The first two paragraphs are an absolute gem.

Comment: Perhaps not "any compact smooth manifold", but "any compact smooth algebraic variety"? For algebraic curves, this is classical.

Comment: This is great, thanks to everyone for their answers!

Comment: I've actually been meaning to ask this for a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 34):

I was Thurston's (undergraduate) student in the mid 1980s, when he was thinking about linkages.  Here's how Thurston explained the proof to me.

By a theorem of Nash (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_functions), any smooth manifold is diffeomorphic to a solution space of a set of real polynomial equations.  So now all one needs to do is devise planar linkages which implement addition and multiplication of real numbers, and hook them together in a way that mirrors the algebraic equations from Nash's theorem.

I never worked through the details of the above sketch myself.

---

[Added: Igor Rivin's answer overlaps with mine, and has additional details.]

Answer (score 26):

It was published here:

M. Kapovich, J. Millson, [Universality theorems for configuration spaces of planar linkages](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-9383(01)00034-9),
Topology 41 (2002), no. 6, 1051–1107.

Answer (score 25):

The result comes by way of Nash's theorem which states that every smooth manifold is a component of a real algebraic variety.

*Nash, John*, [**Real algebraic manifolds**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1969649), Ann. Math. (2) 56, 405-421 (1952). [ZBL0048.38501](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0048.38501).

The game is now to represent a real algebraic variety as a configuration space of a linkage. This is a very old game, going back to Kempe 1876 - the so called [Kempe Universality Theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Kempe%27s_universality_theorem) which states that any real plane algebraic curve can be thus represented. The result of Kapovich and Millson in Andy Putman's answer is a direct descendant of Kempe's result. As far as I know, Thurston did not prove this result, but did give it to Bill Goldman as a Senior Thesis problem. I was under the impression that Goldman solved the problem, but maybe it was a restricted version.

Answer (score 24):

Sometimes the Kempe Universality Theorem 
(see [Igor Rivin's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/295802/6094))
is expressed as: There is a linkage
that signs your name.

---

[image]

---

As an indication of how difficult it is to achieve this in practice, here is a little
linkage that when driven by $b$ rotating on the pinned circle center $a$,
draws a rough approximation to a handwritten letter `J` (purple), drawn out
by joint $z$.

---

[image: Fig2.16]

          

<sup>Fig. 2.16 in *[How To Fold It](http://howtofoldit.org/)*.
Linkage designed by Don Shimamoto.
Computations in [Cinderella](https://www.cinderella.de/tiki-index.php).</sup>

---

Comment: There's something like this at the MIT Museum. http://archive.boston.com/thingstodo/family/gallery/mitmuseum?pg=2

Comment: @TimothyChow: Nice! Here is a 1-minute YouTube video: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJvK47ncVjU).